# Set pom version output into a variable and increment the value

Tags: linux, bash, maven, jenkins

I am working on jenkins, maven, git project. I want to set the version in pom file to auto increment in every new build. I got the version using below command. Version no is 0.0.1.

```
grep -ri "<version>" pom.xml |head -n 1 | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*<version>\([^<]*\) 
<.*$/\1/' | sed 's/[-SNAPSHOT]//g'
```

Now I want to set that values into variables and increment the version in every new build. How can I do it? Is it possible to do? Next build output should be 0.0.2.

Can't I set `0.0.1` output into varibales like `major`, `minor`, `bug` and set `$bug+1`.

Comment: See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53099850/296328

Answer (score 0):

Configure your pom with a new property for ex. `revision` as shown below

```
<version>${revision}</version>  
<properties>
    <revision>0.0.1</revision>
```

Increment the version passing the new version value as a parameter in your maven command as below or you can even use a variable for ex. `new_version`.

`maven clean install -D revision=0.0.2`

`maven clean install -D revision="${new_version}"`

https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html#Multi_Module_Setup

Comment: This will produce WARNINGs in Maven cause this property is not supported. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53099850/296328

Comment: From Macen 3.5.0-beta-1 We can define and use a revision property as described here https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html#Multi_Module_Setup

Comment: In the original post you have used a property `releaseVersion` which will produce a WARNING, cause only `revision`, `changelist` and `sha1` are the allowed properties. I know that you can use that cause I have implemented that and have written that page.